# Plot with bar side by side and with two y axes

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have this script to obtain subplot with bar, but I would rather that the bars were side by side and with two y axes. How can I do? I have in this case the bars one above the other.
The result is shown in figure below.

```
% Create figure
figure1 = figure('NumberTitle','off','Name','Figure','Color',[1 1 1]);
%bar plot e scatter 2011
subplot1=subplot(3,2,1,'Parent',figure1)
x1 = (1:5)';
y1 = tweetsvsnewsS3.somma_1_2;
y2 = tweetsvsnewsS3.tweets_1;
yyaxis left
p1 = bar(x1,y1, 'BarWidth', 0.25);
p1(1).FaceColor = [0.56 0.10 0.74]; 
yyaxis right
p12=bar(x1,y2,'BarWidth', 0.25)
p12(1).FaceColor = [0.41 0.28 0.79]; 
box(subplot1,'on');
hold(subplot1,'off');
set(subplot1,'XGrid','on','XMinorGrid','on','XMinorTick','on','YGrid','on',...
    'YMinorGrid','on','YMinorTick','on');
set(gca,'xtick',1:12,...
 'xticklabel',{'Nov 24','Nov 25','Nov 26','Nov 27','Nov 28'})
ylabel('count');
title('Data','FontSize',12)
```

[image: result]

I tried also this script but I didn't have the second y axis. In figure there is the result.

```
% Create figure
figure1 = figure('NumberTitle','off','Name','Figure','Color',[1 1 1]);
%bar plot e scatter 2011
subplot1=subplot(3,2,1,'Parent',figure1)
x1 = (1:5)';
y1 = tweetsvsnewsS3.somma_1_2;
y2 = tweetsvsnewsS3.tweets_1;
p1 = bar(x1,[y1,y2],'BarWidth', 0.80);
p1(1).FaceColor = [0.56 0.10 0.74]; 
p1(2).FaceColor = [0.41 0.28 0.79]; 
box(subplot1,'on');
hold(subplot1,'off');
set(subplot1,'XGrid','on','XMinorGrid','on','XMinorTick','on','YGrid','on',...
    'YMinorGrid','on','YMinorTick','on');
set(gca,'xtick',1:12,...
 'xticklabel',{'Nov 24','Nov 25','Nov 26','Nov 27','Nov 28'})
ylabel('count');
title('Data','FontSize',12)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to plot the two data sets in the same figure if they don’t even have the same units? If you can’t compare the values, there’s no point in plotting them together.

Comment: Maybe, but the question was how to do that, not if it makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first script is the right one. You can have the bar plotted side by side if you set empty data in each dataset so that we can see the data behind. Note that you must also set the facecolor at the right position in your dataset.

```
[...]
yyaxis left
p1 = bar(x1,[y1 zeros(size(y1))]);
p1(1).FaceColor = [0.56 0.10 0.74]; 
yyaxis right
p12=bar(x1,[zeros(size(y2)) y2]);
p12(2).FaceColor = [0.41 0.28 0.79];
[...]
```